# How to check the process through the internal name of the file

Tags: c#, process

A method that gets the original file name through the process and checks it against the list of process (s). (This could be a `List<string>` and a `string array`)

```
private static bool GetInternalNameProcess(Process p, string match)
{
   string internalname = p.MainModule.FileVersionInfo.InternalName;
   return internalname.ToLower().Equals(match.ToLower(), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
}
```

I create a list of array string array of processes that need to be checked

```
string[] processes = new string[]
{
  "GameExplorer", "GameList", "GameReport", "GameAnalyzer"
};
```

I create a method that runs a check on processes and if it finds a match with processes then it gives a result.

```
public static void Start()
{
   foreach (Process proc in Process.GetProcesses())
   {
     if (GetInternalNameProcess(proc, processes.Contains(proc.ProcessName)) // here I get an error!
     {
        Console.WriteLine("Matches found: " + proc.ProcessName + "");
     }
   }
}
```

> Error CS1503 Argument 2: Cannot convert from "bool" to "string"

How do I implement validation correctly?

---

Added as user @Marlonchosky said, but does not find a match.

```
if (GetInternalNameProcess(proc, processes.SingleOrDefault(x => x == proc.ProcessName) ?? string.Empty))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Matches found: " + proc.ProcessName + "");
}
```

Comment: `processes.Contains(proc.ProcessName)` returns bool, not string, and in your GetInternalNameProcess method, your second parameter is a string

Comment: You could replace `processes.Contains(proc.ProcessName)` for `processes.SingleOrDefault(x => x == proc.ProcessName) ?? string.Empty`

Comment: @Marlonchosky, This did not help, I need to check through the method GetInternalNameProcess

Comment: Then pass the entire `processes` array into your GetInternalNameProcess method.

Comment: @Marlonchosky, Did as you wrote, but does not work :(